# How can I ameliorate this drawing to look more three dimensional?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to draw the following diagram in TikZ :
[image]

Here's my attempt to draw it :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=50mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns, snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, positioning, calc, decorations.text, angles, 
               quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2 ,>=stealth]
    \foreach \i in {0,2} {
    \draw[black, thick] (2,\i) arc [x radius=2, y radius=0.5, start angle=0, end angle=180];
    \draw[black,  thick] (-2,\i) arc [x radius=2, y radius=0.5, start angle=180, end angle=360];
        }
    \draw[->] (2,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=2,x radius=2cm,y radius =1cm] ;
    \node[right] at (2.1,0) {$I$};
    \draw[<-] (2,2) arc [start angle=2,end angle=4,x radius=2cm,y radius =1cm] ;
    \node[right] at (2.1,2) {$I$};
    \draw[->] (0,0)--(-2,0) node[midway, above] {$R$};
    \draw[->] (0,2)--(-2,2) node[midway, above] {$R$};
    \draw[smooth, dashed, ->] (0,-2)--(0,4) node[left] {$z$};
    \filldraw[] (0,0)circle(0.025) node[right] {$O_1$};
    \filldraw[] (0,2)circle(0.025) node[right] {$O_2$};
    \filldraw[] (0,1)circle(0.025) node[left] {$M$};
    \filldraw[] (0,3.5)circle(0.025) node[left] {$N$};
    \filldraw[] (0,-1.5)circle(0.025) node[left] {$P$};
    \draw[smooth, <->] (0.5, 2)--(0.5,3.5) node[right, midway] {$a$};
    \draw[smooth, <->] (0.5, 2)--(0.5, 1) node[right, midway] {$d/2$};
    \draw[smooth, <->] (0.5, 1)--(0.5,0) node[right, midway] {$d/2$};
    \draw[smooth, <->] (0.5, 0)--(0.5,-1.5) node[right, midway] {$b$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Here's the result (that's not satisfying me) I just want to know how can I draw an ellipse with an arrow as the figure shows, and how can I make it look more fancy ?

[image]

Comment: Not much.  You could fill the ellipses (see opacity) and cover the line segments below (drawing everything in sections from the bottom up).

Comment: @JohnKormylo I forgot to mention that the radius looks terrible too

Comment: Note that you are only using TikZ, not tikz-3dplot.  You would have to specify the viewing angle using `\tdplotsetmaincoords`.  Circles are drawn in the x,y plane.

Comment: Problem solved? :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I don't think so :/

Comment: Then please leave a comment below the answer that explains why you are still not happy.

Answer (score 1):

This makes the circles slightly opaque.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2 ,>=stealth]
    \draw[dashed] (0,-2)--(0,0);% bottom
    \filldraw[] (0,-1.5)circle(0.025) node[left] {$P$};
    \draw[<->] (0.5, 0)--(0.5,-1.5) node[right, midway] {$b$};
    
    \fill[white, opacity=0.5] (0,0) circle[x radius=2cm,y radius =0.5cm];
    \draw[black, thick] (0,0) circle[x radius=2cm,y radius =0.5cm];
    \draw[->] (2,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=2,x radius=2cm,y radius =1cm] ;
    \node[right] at (2.1,0) {$I$};
    
    \draw[dashed] (0,0)--(0,2);% middle
    \draw[->] (0,0)--(-2,0) node[midway, above] {$R$};
    \filldraw[] (0,0)circle(0.025) node[right] {$O_1$};
    \draw[<->] (0.5, 1)--(0.5,0) node[right, midway] {$d/2$};
    \draw[<->] (0.5, 2)--(0.5, 1) node[right, midway] {$d/2$};
    \filldraw[] (0,1)circle(0.025) node[left] {$M$};
    
    \fill[white, opacity=0.5] (0,2) circle[x radius=2cm,y radius =0.5cm];
    \draw[black, thick] (0,2) circle[x radius=2cm,y radius =0.5cm];
    \draw[<-] (2,2) arc [start angle=2,end angle=4,x radius=2cm,y radius =1cm] ;
    \node[right] at (2.1,2) {$I$};
    
    \draw[->] (0,2)--(-2,2) node[midway, above] {$R$};
    \draw[dashed, ->] (0,2)--(0,4) node[left] {$z$};% top
    \filldraw[] (0,2)circle(0.025) node[right] {$O_2$};
    \filldraw[] (0,3.5)circle(0.025) node[left] {$N$};
    \draw[<->] (0.5, 2)--(0.5,3.5) node[right, midway] {$a$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

This version uses tikz-3dplot.  If you specify the radius in units (cm), circles will be drawn using screen coordinates instead of the x,y plane.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}% do not use the tikz option of standalone
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, scale=2 ,>=stealth]
    \draw[dashed] (0,0,-2)--(0,0,0);% bottom
    \filldraw[] (0,0,-1.5) circle(0.025cm) node[left] {$P$};
    \draw[<->] (0.5,0, 0)--(0.5,0,-1.5) node[right, midway] {$b$};
    
    \fill[white, opacity=0.5] (0,0,0) circle[radius=2];
    \draw[black, thick] (0,0,0) circle[radius=2];
    \draw[thick, ->] (2,0,0) --(2,0.2,0);
    \node[right] at (2.1,0,0) {$I$};
    
    \draw[dashed] (0,0,0)--(0,0,2);% middle
    \draw[->] (0,0,0)--(-2,0,0) node[midway, above] {$R$};
    \filldraw[] (0,0,0) circle(0.025cm) node[right] {$O_1$};
    \draw[<->] (0.5,0, 1)--(0.5,0,0) node[right, midway] {$d/2$};
    \draw[<->] (0.5,0, 2)--(0.5,0, 1) node[right, midway] {$d/2$};
    \filldraw[] (0,0,1) circle(0.025cm) node[left] {$M$};
    
    \fill[white, opacity=0.5] (0,0,2) circle[radius=2];
    \draw[black, thick] (0,0,2) circle[radius=2];
    \draw[thick, ->] (2,0,2) -- (2,-0.2,2);
    \node[right] at (2.1,0,2) {$I$};
    
    \draw[->] (0,0,2)--(-2,0,2) node[midway, above] {$R$};% top
    \draw[dashed, ->] (0,0,2)--(0,0,4) node[left] {$z$};% top
    \filldraw[] (0,0,2) circle(0.025cm) node[right] {$O_2$};
    \filldraw[] (0,0,3.5) circle(0.025cm) node[left] {$N$};
    \draw[<->] (0.5,0, 2)--(0.5,0,3.5) node[right, midway] {$a$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```